# How to fix google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: The cs.json does not have a valid type. Type is None, expected one of ('authorized_user',

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, audio, video, ffmpeg

**How to fix,** "google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: The file C:\Users\camer\Desktop\Video projects__SCRIPTS_VIDEOMASHUP\client_secret_672522134118-dv5sbe08lbtdi7f9o38k52albg7ms37v.apps.googleusercontent.com.json does not have a valid type. Type is None, expected one of ('authorized_user', 'service_account', 'external_account', 'impersonated_service_account')."

I'm using **anaconda**. I'm trying to get this https://github.com/LamboCreeper/video-mashup to work. I think the problem is my variables aren't set correctly. I use this to setup my google credentials :

[The setting variables attempt][1]
([1]:https://i.stack.imgur.com/w61E8.png)

It returned nothing so I thought it worked.
Then, I ran the next line of code (`python3 video-mashup <source> <destination> <sentence>`) and got this error:

[The code][2]([2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJDFY.png)

Also, I when ran the code, you can see on the first line, I change python3 to python because the code wasnt finding the python.